# Add Spinner dynamically in a loop

Tags: android, android-spinner

I am adding say 'n' spinners in a loop. But only last added spinner is visible when I ran my code. Please see my code below

```
Context context = this;
        ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> list = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();

        ArrayList<String> hi = new ArrayList<String>();
        hi.add("Test 1");
        hi.add("Test 2");

        list.add(hi);

        ArrayList<String> hi1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        hi1.add("Test 3");
        hi1.add("Test 4");

        list.add(hi1);

        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

        alert.setTitle("Test App");
        alert.setMessage("Testing");


        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            final Spinner spinner = (Spinner) layout
                    .findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
            ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list.get(i));

            dataAdapter
                    .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
                    alert.setView(spinner); 
        }

        alert.show();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is happening because all you do in your `for` loop is searching for a `Spinner` in the `Activity`' layout and then using the `setView` method of the `AlertDialog` to add it(this method doesn't add the views to the other `Views` already present, it just replaces them). If you want to add multiple `Spinner` to the same `AlertDialog` you should do it like this:

```
LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
     Spinner spinner = new Spinner(this);
     ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                   android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list.get(i));
     dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
     spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
     LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
     ll.addView(spinner, params);
}
alert.setView(ll);
```

**Edit :**
You can add more views by using a proper layout manager. For example, for a `TextView` and a `Spinner` on the same row you could use a `TableLayout`:

```
    TableLayout tl = new TableLayout(this);
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
        TextView t = new TextView(this);
        t.setText("Text " + i);
        TableRow.LayoutParams params1 = new TableRow.LayoutParams(
                TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        tr.addView(t, params1);
        Spinner spinner = new Spinner(this);
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list.get(i));
        dataAdapter
                .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
        TableRow.LayoutParams params2 = new TableRow.LayoutParams(
                TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        tr.addView(spinner, params2);
        TableLayout.LayoutParams trParams = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                TableLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        tl.addView(tr, trParams);
    }
    alert.setView(tl);
```

Comment: Say I want to add text view to the loop. That is I want to show textview and spinner in same line. How can I do that ? Right now its showing textview and spinner separate line.

Comment: @scooby I've edited my answer. I hope you can figure it from there.

Comment: I also have a TextView and a Spinner on the same line but for that I'm using LinearLayout and creating 15 such layouts in for loop. What do you think - TableLayout is better or 15 LinearLayout?

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria Even if you use a Tablelayout you still need child TableRows and as TableLayout extends Linearlayout it's basically the same. Look into either using a recycling widget(ListView, RecyclerView etc)  or a GridLayout.

Answer (score 0):

You are just setting the same view two times. You need to create a view group (in your case you want a `LinearLayout`) and create several new spinners to put inside it. But if you already know how many spinners you want, you can create a new layout with all the spinners inside it, and then do like this:

```
    LinearLayout viewGroup = (LinearLayout) getInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_spinners, null);

    for (int i = 0; i < viewGroup.getChildCount(); i++) {
        final Spinner spinner = (Spinner) viewGroup.getChildAt(i);

        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list.get(i));

        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    }
    alert.setView(viewGroup);

    alert.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

This line...

```java
final Spinner spinner = (Spinner) layout.findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
```

is always getting the same spinner from your layout every iteration of the loop. You probably want to dynamically create this every iteration.

And this line...

```java
alert.setView(spinner);
```

is always setting the alert's view as the single spinner that you previously loaded.

You should try something like this instead

```java
LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    final Spinner spinner = new Spinner(getApplicationContext());
    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list.get(i));
    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    layout.addView(spinner); 
}

alert.setView(layout);
```