# linear layout java and xml

Tags: java, android, xml, layout

I'm just trying to add spinners dynamicallyand I found my way here [Add Spinner dynamically in a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10460489/add-spinner-dynamically-in-a-loop)
that works good but my issue is the view takes place instead of my original layout (a header, a footer and an image view).
I would like to place it in a specific layout in the xml file, between the header and the footer for example.
Is there a way to do this?
my code

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Intent i = getIntent();
    conteneur = "container No : " + i.getStringExtra("container");
    conteneur_s = i.getStringExtra("container");
    fichano = i.getStringExtra("fichano");
    pos = i.getIntExtra("pos", 0);
    latitude = i.getDoubleExtra("geolat", 0);
    longitude = i.getDoubleExtra("geolon", 0);
    volume = i.getStringExtra("volume");
    saver = i.getStringExtra("saver");
    poids = i.getStringExtra("poids");
    tel = i.getStringExtra("telpass");
    driver = i.getStringExtra("driverpass");
    tour = i.getStringExtra("tour");

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_parc);
    container = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nom);
    container.setText(conteneur);
    RelativeLayout lr = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.full_layout);

    GradientDrawable gd = new GradientDrawable(
            GradientDrawable.Orientation.TOP_BOTTOM,
            new int[] {0xFFFFFFFF,0xFFB0B0B0});
    gd.setCornerRadius(0f);
    lr.setBackground(gd);
    showImg = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);


    String pathparc = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/SmartCollecte/PARC/PARAM";
    File f = new File(pathparc);
    final File file[] = f.listFiles();

    LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(MAIN_parcActivity.this);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(140, 398);
    layoutParams.setMargins(24, 50, 24, 0);
    layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    for (int j = 0; j < file.length; j++) {
        String[] namewext;
        namewext = FilenameUtils.removeExtension(file[j].getName()).split("_");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),namewext[1],Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Spinner spinner = new Spinner(getApplicationContext());
        String[]choix = new String[]{"choisissez"+j, "Propreté", "Détérioration", "Accès", "Maintenance", "autre"};
        List<String> str = new ArrayList<>();
        str.add(namewext[1]);
        Collections.addAll(str,choix);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MAIN_parcActivity.this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, str);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        layout.addView(spinner);
        setContentView(layout,layoutParams);

    }


}
```

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/full_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#909090"

>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/header"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="60sp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="#E25D63"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:weightSum="3">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="60sp"
        android:layout_height="60sp"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:src="@drawable/backinblack"
        android:background="#CFCFCF"
        android:layout_weight="0.20"
        android:onClick="fermer"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nom"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#220c0c"
        android:text="Tournée"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:paddingLeft="30dp"
        android:paddingRight="30dp"
        android:paddingTop="4dp"
        android:paddingBottom="4dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.80"
        android:background="#E25D63"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        >
    </TextView>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"

        android:src="@drawable/anom_ctn"
        android:layout_weight="0.20"
        android:background="#CFCFCF"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        />

</LinearLayout>

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/scroll"
    android:layout_below="@+id/header"
    android:layout_above="@+id/footer"
    android:fillViewport="true">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id = "@+id/spin"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="10dip"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            >
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="Etat de parc"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"/>


        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id = "@+id/spin2"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="10dip"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/spin">


            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/gametime"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:prompt="@string/anomalie"
                android:visibility="visible"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/boutons"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="10dip"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/spin2">

        </LinearLayout>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_below="@id/boutons"
            android:layout_margin="40sp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"></ImageView>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/footer"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="60sp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="#cfcfcf"
    android:weightSum="3"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    >
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:src="@drawable/photo"
        android:layout_weight="0.80"
        android:paddingRight="30sp"
        android:onClick="photo"
        android:clickable="true"
        />


    <View android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1.40"/>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:src="@drawable/validation_test"
        android:layout_weight="0.80"
        android:paddingTop="10sp"

        android:paddingLeft="25sp"
        android:onClick="enregistrer"
        android:clickable="true"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding a view to a LinearLayout at a specified position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6917496/adding-a-view-to-a-linearlayout-at-a-specified-position)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not terribly sure here, I wonder if it is replacing the view because you aren't setting a unique ID for each view? That or failing to call `layout.invalidate()` after finishing a run through the loop.

Comment: T-he-game the views in the loop shows good. This is my layout that doesn't appear anymore

Comment: The spinner replaces the LinearLayout?

Comment: exactly T-he-game